JSON Serialize and Deserialize using different property names in
Using System.Text.Json, I have a client app that only reads properties from a class on my API. My API, calls an external API to get some data first and then returns it to my client app.
What I'm trying to accomplish is to use 1 class in my API, which will read/parse the json from the external source using their naming concepts, while my API spits out the same class with different property names.
For example:
public class Event {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

external API returns { "event_id": 1, "ourName" : "Test" }, and my API should return to my client as { "id" : 1, "name" : "Test }
I know I can create a separate model and then manually (or with AutoMapper) map the fields.
I'm looking for a way, maybe using some sort of Attribute where I can define the name to use for serialization and another name for deserialization. Something like this, where the serialization will just use the name of the property, but ddserialization will use the attribute.
public class Event {
    [JsonDeserialize("event_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonDeserialize("ourName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

I'm sure I'm not the first to want this, but my searching skills are lacking as I haven't found anything. Maybe I'm not searching for the correct keywords.
Thanks!

People don't do this because it's very fragile. Creating two different classes is very cheap and mapping between them only needs property assignments. It's almost the same number of codes as adding the (nonexistent) attributes. You can add a conversion operator or method to one of the classes that will take as many lines as the attributes. If the names were similar you could use AutoMapper to map one DTO to the other based on naming conventions. With so different names though, you'd need to add one line per property. Again, as many as the assignments

Thanks. Probably why I'm not seeing much results. I do see several when it comes to JSON.net using DefaultContractResolvers but nothing for System.Text.Json

@PanagiotisKanavos BTW: The reason I prefer an Attribute style solution, is because I have to do this with many fields and 20 other Classes form the external API. Feels Like a lot to have to create 40 classes for this.

Maybe it feels like a lot, because it is a lot, but the only right way in the long shot is to divide and conquer. And using 40 different classes is maybe a bunch, but in case of errors or changes it is a no brainer, because you just worry about one of your 40 classes. When you have one super class that can handle all 40 cases and then you have to change something for one class you have to think about the impact on the 39 other cases too. Believe me, this will get messy. Don't try it. Others tried before you and they all failed.

We have a bigger rest api and when our api is called we create class A instance with the incoming data. After validation it will be transformed into a class B instance, goes down into the business layer where it will be transformed in one or multiple instances of class C, D and / or E. The business layer will create a response object of class F which bubbles up to the controller. The controller will create a class G api response object that will be returned as JSON. That's IMHO a normal flow, involves a lot of classes, but makes maintenance easy.

Thanks @Oliver! I appreciate it. Yeah we currently do the same for our API: class A represents exactly what's in the DB, then it's transformed to class B to processing, etc. then sent to the controller with class C as you said. Thanks!

Starting with .NET 7 you can use a JsonTypeInfo modifier to set up alternate names for properties when serializing from/to the external API.  See this answer to Asymmetric Field Names for serialisation and deserialisation using System.Text.Json.  In fact I think that question is a duplicate of yours since the answer also uses custom attributes to specify 3rd party alternate names, agree?

@dbc Thanks I'll look into this and report back.

Finally got around to test it and it works great! Thank you @dbc

Have you tried using [JsonPropertyName("ExternalJsonPropertyName")]?
Here you will find more about this if you haven't seen this already.
If this isnt what you are looking for then i apologize, i may have not understood your problem correctly

This fixes the name for all serializations

Yes, I'm currently using that, but as @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned that doesn't solve the issue: serialize with one name and deserialize with another.
